# Moving to Mobile environment

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, amazon-web-services, umbraco7, devexpress-mvc

We have built  kind of eCommerce site using Umbraco CMS. Now we have plan of creating new site for mobile users like m.abc.com (not mobile App), so that we can redirect all mobile devices to m.abc.com. Therefore before starting I would like to know best practices.

1. We have devexpress license can I use any specific controls which helps us to deliver software quickly.
2. We are planning to go with MVC4 ,any best practices to optimize the performance of application.
3. We are going to host this application in AWS. Any AWS specific features for mobile site developement?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a subjective question so there's no correct answer for this, but so far this is what I've done based on my experience and it worked fine for me:

- Manage the redirections with [51degrees.com](https://51degrees.com/) it got a "free"
  product with a decent database for device detection just be aware
  that tablet redirection is just supported on the premium version
- Use bootstrap or devexpress and try to target tablets and smartphones with the same front end
- Use the same backend, try to expose the functionalities you need through web services, REstful services in that matter try to avoid to repeat yourself as much as you can, having a duplicated codebase for the same functionality will be a nightmare
- Once you are ready for deployment remove the unused css of your application try [uncss](https://github.com/addyosmani/grunt-uncss) it's a grunt tool (based on node.js and npm) that works perfectly with any front end, almost every application uses from 10% to 20% of the css provided by any framework
- In terms of web server (I guess you're using IIS) set up a cache for static elements such as css, images and other files

my two cents.